# (c++) using lambdas as nested functions, or even as general functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

```
enum { WITH_ZERO };
auto copy_num = [](int n, char target[NUM_LEN]) -> int {
    char temp;
    for (int j = NUM_LEN - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if ((temp = n % 10 + '0') == '0') {
            return WITH_ZERO;
        } else {
            target[j] = temp;
            n /= 10;
        }
    }
    return !WITH_ZERO;
};
if (copy_num(i, num_copy) == WITH_ZERO) {
    continue;
}
if (i * 3 > MAX_NUM) {
    continue;
}
copy_num(i * 2, num_double);
copy_num(i * 3, num_triple);
```

//edit: changed 'goto' to 'continue'

The above is part of my code, which should show in what cases I would prefer to use nested lambdas. I can achieve similar to this with macros, but they do make my codes dirtier, while the lambdas used this way look more clean, without the '\'s. The 'copy_num' function here is only used locally and not anywhere else, so this has more readability than when defining 'copy_num' as a normal function outside. Lambdas can also conveniently catch outer variables if needed, in which case I can reduce repetitive function parameters, again making clearer code.

By using lambdas this way several times, I wondered whether it is a good or bad idea to use lambdas as an entire replacement to functions. Lambdas can work perfectly well as a more flexible form of functions possible to be nested or anonymous. In cases where what the lambdas do are of no difference than what a normal function of a same form would do, the compiler will be smart enough to compile them as if being plain functions.

Or perhaps future c/c++ will allow nested functions in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is anything wrong with this approach. It is certainly safer than C'ish `#define's`, the savings in `\`s being the least advantage I can think of.

Until lambda support has matured, you may see compilers struggle to generate 'optimal' code though.

> Lambdas can also conveniently catch outer variables if needed, in which case I can reduce repetitive function parameters, again making clearer code.

Yes, and once needed elsewhere, the lambda + capture can easily be migrated to a class that holds state and defines some operations on it.

> Or perhaps future c/c++ will allow nested functions in general?

This *is* fully-fleshed support for nested functions. Remember, a lambda that does not capture can decay to a function pointer.